# Efficient Joins with the same big table

Tags: sql, performance, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to join a table on itself with a big resultset (+ 6M rows).

I have the following table

| Period | Zone | TAG | NAME | PROGRAM | COST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-01 | EMEA | A | User2 | Program 2 | 98 |
| 2020-11-01 | APAC | A | User2 | Program 2 | 103 |
| 2020-12-01 | NA | A | User2 | Program 2 | 118 |
| 2020-10-01 | NA | X | User3 | Program 3 | 334 |
| 2020-11-01 | EMEA | X | User3 | Program 3 | 362 |
| 2020-12-01 | APAC | X | User3 | Program 3 | 380 |

I would like an efficient query with this kind of output (no values can be 0 or null i don't mind):

| Period | Zone | TAG | NAME | PROGRAM | COST | COST EMEA | COST APAC | COST NA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-01 | EMEA | A | User2 | Program 2 | 98 | 98 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-11-01 | APAC | A | User2 | Program 2 | 103 | 0 | 103 | 0 |
| 2020-12-01 | NA | A | User2 | Program 2 | 118 | 0 | 0 | 118 |
| 2020-10-01 | NA | X | User3 | Program 3 | 334 | 0 | 0 | 334 |
| 2020-11-01 | EMEA | X | User3 | Program 3 | 362 | 362 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-12-01 | APAC | X | User3 | Program 3 | 380 | 0 | 380 | 0 |

If i do the following query it takes ages:

```
WITH TOTAL AS (
SELECT Period,Zone,TAG,NAME,PROGRAM,COST
FROM "DB"."SCHEMA"."Table"
)
SELECT T.*,E."COST" AS "COST EMEA",A."COST" AS "COST APAC",N."COST" AS "COST NA"
FROM TOTAL T , TOTAL E, TOTAL A, TOTAL N
WHERE T."Period" = E."Period" 
AND T."Period" = A."Period"
AND T."Period" = N."Period"
```

How could i improve this query ? There an efficient way to perform it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query will take a long time to run because it's doing a cartesian product of rows where the period ID is the same, 3 times (3 joins). It'll also produce wrong results I think.

If I understand your question correctly I think you're looking for something like this:

```sql
WITH TOTAL AS (
    SELECT
        Period,
        Zone,
        TAG,
        NAME,
        PROGRAM,
        COST
    FROM test_table
)
SELECT
    total.*,
    iff(upper(zone) = 'EMEA', cost, 0) as COST_EMEA,
    iff(upper(zone) = 'APAC', cost, 0) as COST_APAC,
    iff(upper(zone) = 'NA', cost, 0) as COST_NA
from total
;
```

This produces the following table (I think your example results are incorrect. The last line of your table associates the cost to `NA` where it should be `APAC`.):

| PERIOD | ZONE | TAG | NAME | PROGRAM | COST | COST_EMEA | COST_APAC | COST_NA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-01 | EMEA | A | User2 | Program 2 | 98 | 98 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-11-01 | APAC | A | User2 | Program 2 | 103 | 0 | 103 | 0 |
| 2020-12-01 | NA | A | User2 | Program 2 | 118 | 0 | 0 | 118 |
| 2020-10-01 | NA | X | User3 | Program 3 | 334 | 0 | 0 | 334 |
| 2020-11-01 | EMEA | X | User3 | Program 3 | 362 | 362 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-12-01 | APAC | X | User3 | Program 3 | 380 | 0 | 380 | 0 |